# Find number of positive integer solutions to the equation $a+b+c=15$ where a,b are even and c is odd

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

This is equivalent to:

Coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{14})^2(x+x^3+\cdots+x^{15})$

Or

Coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{14})^3$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: $c=1+2k$, $a+b=14-2k=2(7-k)$. For each $c=1+2k$ there are $6-k$ solutions. Then total number of positive integer solutions with even $a$ and $b$ and odd $c$ is $\sum_{k=0}^5 (6-k)=\sum_{n=1}^{6} n=21$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "positive" rather than "non-negative", so it is

- the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{14})^2(x+x^3+\cdots+x^{15})$

which is

- the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $(x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{12})^2(x+x^3+\cdots+x^{11})$
- the coefficient of $x^{16}$ in $(x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{12})^3$
- the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{10})^3$
- the coefficient of $x^{5}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{5})^3$

which is ${7 \choose 2}=21$

That is short enough to list as a check:

```
2 + 2 + 11
2 + 4 + 9
2 + 6 + 7
2 + 8 + 5
2 + 10 + 3
2 + 12 + 1
4 + 2 + 9
4 + 4 + 7
4 + 6 + 5
4 + 8 + 3
4 + 10 + 1
6 + 2 + 7
6 + 4 + 5
6 + 6 + 3
6 + 8 + 1
8 + 2 + 5
8 + 4 + 3
8 + 6 + 1
10 + 2 + 3
10 + 4 + 1
12 + 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's already been pointed out that the OP has an error in that $a,b,c$ are supposed to be positive, not non-negative.

But I would like to point out that the algebra is a little simpler if we use  the constraints $a,b,c \ge 1$ *without* taking into account our knowledge that $a,b,c \le 15$.  This gives the generating function
$$\begin{align} 
f(x) &= (x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + \dots)^2 (x + x^3 + x^6 + \dots) \\
&= x^5 (1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots)^3 \\
&= x^5 \left( \frac {1}{1-x^2} \right)^3 \\
&= x^5 (1-x^2)^{-3} \\
&= x^5 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{3+i-1}{i} x^{2i}
\end{align}$$
From the last equation we see that the coefficient of $x^{15}$ is $\binom{7}{5} = 21$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just solving the problem with a direct approach? You know that $a$ and $b$ are even and $c$ is odd, so $a = 2A, b = 2B$, and $c = 2C+1$, with $A,B$ positive integers and $C \geq 0$. Now the problem amounts to solving
$$2(A+B+C)+1 = 15,$$
so you want $A,B > 0$ and $C \geq 0$ integers such that
$$A+B+C = 7.$$
You can just do this by trying case by case.

Comment: Agree, and then we can use stars and bars theorem

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You can just find all triples that work, you do not have much choice...

Comment: @Gibbs Finding positive integer solutions to $A+B+C=7$ is equivalent to finding non-negative integer solutions to $X+Y+Z=4$ which is $\binom {6}{2}=15$ but Henry's answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: @ParthShresth  $A+B+C=7$ requires $A$ and $B$ positive and $C$ non-negative, so $X+Y+Z=5$ with $X,Y,Z$ non-negative

Comment: @Henry Ah! Okay

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was sloppy in the wording. The answer was just meant to suggest a more direct way.

Comment: @Gibbs your answer was great! But I just wanted to know if the answer could be obtained with my approach too.